# Firefox "This browser or app may not be secure" when trying to log in with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

when i run this code in other pc it works, but when i run the code in my own pc mozilla shows me this window saying

heres my code:

```
AUTOMATION_FAILED = False
USE_FAILSAFE_PERCAUTIONS = True
MEET_CODE = "xxx-xxx-xxx"
EMAIL_ADDRESS = "myaccount"
AD_USERNAME = ""
AD_PASSWORD = "mypasswrd."

options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.set_preference('media.navigator.permission.disabled', True)

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")  # Absolute path to Firefox executable
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options, firefox_binary=binary)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier")
print("Successfully loaded Google Authetication point! [Gmail]")

time.sleep(2)

if AUTOMATION_FAILED == False:
    for i in range(6):
        try:
            driver.find_element("id", "identifierId").send_keys(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
            driver.find_element("id", "identifierNext").click()
            print("Sucessfully uploaded email...")
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("[ERROR]: Attempting to resend email address.")
            if USE_FAILSAFE_PERCAUTIONS:
                time.sleep(6)
            else:
                driver.implicitly_wait(6)
        except WebDriverException as e:
            print("[ERROR]: Web driver error.\n[ERROR DETAILS]:", e)
            AUTOMATION_FAILED = True
            break

if AUTOMATION_FAILED == False:
    if AD_USERNAME == "" or AD_USERNAME == None:
        for i in range(6):
            try:
                driver.find_element("name", "Passwd").send_keys(AD_PASSWORD)
                driver.find_element("id", "passwordNext").click()
                print("Sucessfully sent credentials...")
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("[ERROR]: Attempting to find password input.")
                if USE_FAILSAFE_PERCAUTIONS:
                    time.sleep(6)
                else:
                    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    else:
        for i in range(6):
            try:
                driver.find_element("id", "userNameInput").send_keys(AD_USERNAME)
                driver.find_element("id", "passwordInput").send_keys(AD_PASSWORD)
                driver.find_element("id", "passwordNext").click()
                print("Sucessfully sent Active Directory credentials...")
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("[ERROR]: Attempting to find active directory login elements.")
                if USE_FAILSAFE_PERCAUTIONS:
                    time.sleep(6)
                else:
                    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
            except WebDriverException as e:
                print("[ERROR]: Web driver error.\n[ERROR DETAILS]:", e)
                AUTOMATION_FAILED = True
                break

time.sleep(6)
print("Loading Google Meets...")
driver.get(f"https://meet.google.com/{MEET_CODE}")
# driver.refresh()
```

I saw many other  posts with similar problem and i treied to follow the solutions but nothing that i tried work, if something is wrong i apologize, im tottally new with selenium and i just copy and paste this code from a partner

Comment: "mozilla shows me this window saying...." You didn't tell us what the window was saying.

Comment: You're getting detected. Maybe try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Comment: try using cookies or user profiles to skip the login process and avoid the problem